# Link to task page in email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've created an `Approval Workflow` that runs when an item is added to a list. At creation of a new item, the workflow starts and sends an email to a specific user.

The problem is, I want to add a **link inside the email** that **directs the user to the task page** - the place from where he can approve or reject the item.

How can I do that?

How will the user get to complete the task if I don't direct him there by e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

The field that provides the URL to the Approve/Reject page is the **[%Current Task:Form_URN]** lookup that provides the information.
No building out necessary. Note that this solution will work in SPD 2010 workflows

Answer (score -1):

You need to choose `Workflow Context` from *`fx`* and choose `Current Item  Url`

[Follow here](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2011/02/18/sharepoint-designer-2010-email-link-to-item.aspx)